# how many uvicorn workers do I have to have in production?

Tags: gunicorn, fastapi, uvicorn

## My Environment

- FastAPI
- Gunicorn & Uvicorn Worker
- AWS EC2 c5.2xlarge (8 vCPU)

## Document

https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/server-workers/

## Question

Currently I'm using 24 Uvicorn workers in production server. (c5.2xlarge)

`gunicorn main:app --workers 24 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --bind 0.0.0.0:80`

I've learn that one process runs on one core.
Therefore If i have 8 processes, I can make use of whole cores (c5.2xlarge's vCpu == 8)

I'm curious that in this situation, Is there any performance benefit if I got more processes than 8?

Comment: (most EC2s) 1 vCPU = 1 Thread, and each core has 2 threads. so in your case c5.2xlarge = 4 cpu cores https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/cpu-options-supported-instances-values.html

Answer (score 15):

Number of recommended workers is `2 x number_of_cores +1`

You can read more about it at
[https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#:~:text=Gunicorn%20should%20only%20need%204,workers%20to%20start%20off%20with](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#:%7E:text=Gunicorn%20should%20only%20need%204,workers%20to%20start%20off%20with).

In your case with 8 CPU cores, you should be using 17 worker threads.

Additional thoughts on async systems:

The two times core is not a scientific figure as says in the article. But the idea is that one thread can do I/O and another CPU processing at the same time. This makes maximum use of simultaneous threads. Even with async systems, conceptually this works and should give you maximum efficiency.

Comment: Thank you! But I'm curious is this applicable to async workers? Since they can process other thing while waiting for the IO (due to event loop)

Comment: I have added this in the answer. For everyone's reference.

Answer (score 7):

In general the best practice is:

```
number_of_workers = number_of_cores x 2 + 1
```

or more precisely:

```
number_of_workers = number_of_cores x num_of_threads_per_core + 1
```

--> **BUT** be careful not to confuse number_of_cores with vCPU.

The reason for it is CPU hyperthreading, which allows each core to run multiple concurrent threads. The number of concurrent threads is decided by the chip designers.

**Two** concurrent threads per CPU core are common, but some processors can support more than two.

**vCPU** that is mentioned for AWS ec2 resource is already the hyperthreaded amount of processing units you have on the machine (`num_of_cores x num_of_threads_per_core`). Not to be confused with `number_of_cores` available on that machine.

So, in your case, `c5.2xlarge` has `8 vCPUs`, meaning you have `8` available concurrent workers.

Comment: So he should run --workers 9 ( number_of_workers =  number_of_cores x num_of_threads_per_core + 1 = 8 + 1  ) and the accepted answer is in fact misleading ?

Comment: For the time of writing there is no accepted answer, but if you mean, should he run 8 vCPUs x 2 + 1 = 17, so probably not as he will choke the workers when high traffic will hit and workers would like to do 17 concurrent CPU operations while having only 8 available.