# How many server workers per microservice - Gunicorn with Uvicorn in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, gunicorn, uvicorn

I'm not sure how many workers should I declare per every FastAPI based microservice.
Some information I found here:
[gunicorn - how many unicorn workers do I have to have in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72374634/how-many-uvicorn-workers-do-i-have-to-have-in-production)

As I understand number of workers should be:

```
number_of_workers = number_of_cores x num_of_threads_per_core + 1
```

So if I have 4 services based on FastAPI and my processor have `4 cores` and `8 threads` I should divide workers per service? Like for example:

```
number_of_workers = 4 x 8 + 1
number_of_workers = 33

fastapi_service_1 - 9 workers
fastapi_service_2 - 8 workers
fastapi_service_3 - 8 workers
fastapi_service_4 - 8 workers
```

Answer (score 0):

fastapi_service - in this case, 4 workers

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).